# Way to add a border of different color to top and bottom edge of an android view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have a TextView and I'd like to add border with different colors along its top and bottom edges. I know that inorder to add a border of one color along all edges we can simply use following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

But what needs to be done if we require edges with different colors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're quite close to what you want, what you need to do is add another item below your default item. Those two items are your top/bottom borders. By add bottom/top 1dp to both, you reveal the two colours.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```